# How to create dynamic blog asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I am developing my own blog. I am planning to develop a dynamic blog. I have searched a lot but didn't get any idea how do I create it dynamically? `Blog post` can have images, text. How do I manage it dynamically ? Is there any sample project?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are, this one is rather nice. The code is pretty old so you would have to update that parts to modern MVC etc but the ideas are sound.

ASP.NET MVC Press(WordPress like)/Blog Sample application.

Multi Tenant Blogging System Standard Features

- A Wordpress like clone allowing for multiple blogs
- Blog functionality including: Posts, Post, Comments with CAPTCHA, Tags, Categories, Links, Link Categories, Blog/Post RSS
- Password protected Blog Administration including Tag, Post and Comments Management
  -- User Authentication and User Authorization

Architecture:

- ASP.NET MVC
- Linq to SQL
- StructureMap Dependency Injection
- Distributed Caching (via Memcached, ScaleOut SOSS, and Velocity)

[You can read more about it here and download the source](http://mvcpress.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Is this project still active? :S

Comment: Alive as still developed? No I would not think so, but Ajay Punekar was requesting examples of how to build a blog engine and for that purpose this code would be well suited as he can't really copy paste it but rather read the code and take away general ideas from it.

Comment: :) I'd never heard of it. Nice example

Comment: @karl-henrik Thanks for reply. I just want an idea. I will go through this example.

Answer (score 1):

Try [BlogEngine.net](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET)! it is open source, google search for more!

Comment: the provided url is broken , the github link is here [here](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET) 
and if you looking to ready to use hosting with this project it's available [here](https://blogengine.io)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find an up to date and complete example anywhere.

Usually things like blogs use a database to save their posts. So I'd make a mysql database with a few tables to save your posts in. After you made this you can make a content creating page (where you create your blog posts and save them to your DB).

To show your posts you can call a page that expects a variable in your URL, the variable being the ID/name of the post in your DB. Then simply use a select query to get your post from DB and fill in your page with the values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I can store the data in DB. But if I have one post which contains images. So how can I display it dynamically. Post can have images on different location in a post. The location of images is not fixed. It's depends on my blog post. So how can I manage that ?

Comment: You could save your text as HTML instead of plain text, allowing it to have image tags. Your page showing the post will need an HTML container though.